# How can I set up localStorage keys with storageState

Tags: playwright, e2e

I'm trying to set up localStorage when a user registers,
but it only generates the file with no key, values.

If I run `npx playwright codegen --save-storage=formsData.json`
works fine and generates the key,values but the generated code is very different
and I don't see how localStorage is created.

What I'm doing wrong, or not doing ?

This is my test code:

```js
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');
const { buildUser } = require('./utils/generateUser');

test.describe('Register Form', () => {
    test('displays register form and can register user', async ({ browser }) => {
    const user = await buildUser();
    
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/register');
    
    await expect(page).toHaveURL('http://localhost:3000/register');
    
    const firstNameInput = page.locator('[placeholder="Nombre"]');
    const lastNameInput = page.locator('[placeholder="Apellidos"]');
    const emailInput = page.locator('[placeholder="Email"]');
    const passwordInput = page.locator('[placeholder="Contraseña"]');
    const repeatPasswordInput = page.locator('[placeholder="Repite la contraseña"]');
    const registerButton = page.locator('text=Adelante');
    const termsCheckbox = page.locator('input[type="checkbox"]').first();
    const privacyCheckbox = page.locator('input[type="checkbox"]').last();
    const modalWindow = page.locator('.styles__ContentWrapper-n48cq5-0');
    const modalButton = page.locator('text=Aceptar');
    
    await expect(firstNameInput).toBeEmpty();
    await expect(lastNameInput).toBeEmpty();
    await expect(emailInput).toBeEmpty();
    await expect(passwordInput).toBeEmpty();
    await expect(repeatPasswordInput).toBeEmpty();
    await expect(registerButton).toBeDisabled();
    await expect(termsCheckbox).not.toBeChecked();
    await expect(privacyCheckbox).not.toBeChecked();
    await expect(modalWindow).toBeHidden();
    
    await firstNameInput.fill(user.nombre);
    await lastNameInput.fill(user.apellido);
    await emailInput.fill(user.email);
    await passwordInput.fill('12341234');
    await repeatPasswordInput.fill('12341234');
    await termsCheckbox.check();
    await privacyCheckbox.click();
    
    await expect(modalWindow).toBeVisible();
    
    await page.press(':nth-match(input[type="checkbox"], 2)', 'Tab');    
    await page.press('text=info@coinscrap.com', 'Tab');
        
    await await modalButton.click();
    
    await expect(registerButton).toBeEnabled();
    await registerButton.click();
    
    await page.context().storageState({ path: 'formsData.json' });
    await browser.close();
  });
});
```

This is what playwright codegen does:

```js
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');
test('test', async ({ page }) => {
      // Go to http://localhost:3000/register
      await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/register');
      // Click [placeholder="Nombre"]
      await page.click('[placeholder="Nombre"]');
      // Fill [placeholder="Nombre"]
      await page.fill('[placeholder="Nombre"]', 'Pascale');
      // Click [placeholder="Apellidos"]
      await page.click('[placeholder="Apellidos"]');
      // Fill [placeholder="Apellidos"]
      await page.fill('[placeholder="Apellidos"]', 'Gusikowski');
      // Click [placeholder="Email"]
      await page.click('[placeholder="Email"]');
      // Fill [placeholder="Email"]
      await page.fill('[placeholder="Email"]', 'Pascale_Gusikowski86@gmail.com');
      // Click [placeholder="Contraseña"]
      await page.click('[placeholder="Contraseña"]');
      // Fill [placeholder="Contraseña"]
      await page.fill('[placeholder="Contraseña"]', '12341234');
      // Click [placeholder="Repite la contraseña"]
      await page.click('[placeholder="Repite la contraseña"]');
      // Fill [placeholder="Repite la contraseña"]
      await page.fill('[placeholder="Repite la contraseña"]', '12341234');
      // Check input[type="checkbox"]
      await page.check('input[type="checkbox"]');
      // Click text=1.1 -Decisiones automatizadas, perfiles y lógica aplicada Los datos recogidos me
      await page.click('text=1.1 -Decisiones automatizadas, perfiles y lógica aplicada Los datos recogidos me');
      // Press End
      await page.press('text=You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. Crea una cuenta​​​​​ AdelanteHe l', 'End');
      // Click text=Aceptar
      await page.click('text=Aceptar');
      // Click text=Adelante
      await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation(/*{ url: 'http://localhost:3000/internal/banks/start' }*/),
        page.click('text=Adelante')
      ]);
});
```

There's no code where localStorage is created.
I need to do it programmatically.

I've also tried with:

```js
const localStorage = await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(window.localStorage));
fs.writeFileSync('formsData.json', localStorage);
```

It generates the file but didn't generate keys, values.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage (DOMStorage) is unrelated to the form you submit. When you submit the form, a POST request is typically issued to the server, sending on this data to the backend. It looks like your page has additional JavaScript code that stores these values into localStorage at some point. Your localStorage does not have these values at the time you save it, so you should figure out how to trigger this code on your page and how to wait for it. You can open DevTools and evaluate "localStorage" in console or pick it in the Application tab to see when and why these values make their way into the local storage.

Comment: I could make it work, but I had to put all the tests in a one single file. Still don't know why this happens but it works. Yes, the page has additional JavaScript code that stores these values into localStorage at some point. Those values are used to keep track the user data so that they aren't lost if page refreshes or if user clicks back button.